# Uploading MySQL database

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

I'm developing a Java project on netBeans using an Apache Tomcat server and MySQL database.
I have succefully uploaded the war file to Amazon Web Services (AWS), but I couldn't uploaded the database.
I tried to upload it using RDS on AWS management console, but I haven't seen an option to import my existing db to there (tables or data).
Does someone have any idea how I can do it? Or where can I upload my database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use mysqldump command to dump the data from your local DB to a file. Once the file is available import it. 
For RDS use this [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MySQL.Procedural.Importing.SmallExisting.html)